# Bootstrap datepicker - adding tooltip on specified date of specific month

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Tooltip is working fine, 
The problem I couldn't set tooltip only date of the specific month,

If I set tooltip 5th date of the current month but tooltip adding on 5th date of each month

```
$('.date-header').datepicker({
          autoclose: true,
          beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var hilightedDays = [5,6];
            if (~hilightedDays.indexOf(date.getDate()) && ( hilightedDays) ) {
                return {classes: 'highlight', tooltip: 'Example Tooltip data' }
            }}
        }).on('show',function(e, date) {
          $('td.highlight').tooltip();
        });
```

no input filed because Here I am not picking any date just adding information as tooltop

```
<div class="calendar-block ">
    <span class="date-header calendar--btn d-flex text-center align-items-center "><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
  </div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShibinRagh/8fc9vhg1/10/)

And is it possible to add date-picker shows toggle-style when clicking on the calendar button

Comment: Use `$('td.highlight').tooltip({ container: 'body' });` to avoid dates flickering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the date to apply to the current month, you could get that value and check to see if the month being viewed in the datepicker is equal to the current month.

Something like this:

```
$('.date-header').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var hilightedDays = [5, 6];

      // get current month
      var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();

      // if date.getMonth() === currentMonth, then highlight the date
      if (date.getMonth() === currentMonth && ~hilightedDays.indexOf(date.getDate()) && (hilightedDays)) {
        return {
          classes: 'highlight',
          tooltip: 'Example Tooltip data'
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Likewise, you could use any month value (e.g., if you only wanted to show the tooltip in September, just check to see if month === 8; months are 0-based so 0 is January and 11 is December).

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bt0hysqm/

Comment: Great , working fine but not working if I come back after next/prev month click @AndroidNoobie

Comment: Solved, Called tooltip again inside beforeShowMonth

Comment: Why //& (hilightedDays)// this in condition ?

Comment: I just reused the code in your original post. I only added the check for if `date.getMonth() === currentMonth`.